# Is there any way to overcome URL length limitation in REST API "GET" Requests?

Tags: client-object-model, rest, api

Is there any way to overcome the 2083 characters limit using REST API GET request itself.

Answer (score 0):

Technically I HttpGet will have issue if the URL length goes beyond 2000 characters. In that case, it's better to use HttpPost or redesign the URL schema.

Check here for pretty well explanation: https://boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html
In Summary:
The maximum length of a URL in Internet Explorer is 2,083 characters
Firefox: 65,536 characters
Safari:80,000 characters
opera: 190,000 characters

Comment: Ya Farshid, If length is greater than approx 2k we can go with REST API Post requests or some other client object models. But I'm trying to overcome the limitation for GET requests

Answer (score 0):

You may require custom service to be written. Other than that I dont see any method. REST is the more capable when quering SharePoint even we think of other methods like CSOM or server side code.